# Downsides of creating new collections for the same data in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

My app saves alot of data from different companies on the same format, is it better perfomance wise to have a single collection and separate them by a `companyId key` or to have  multiple collections following a naming pattern like company_{companyId}?

Comment: _It depends_. It depends upon factors like the number of documents, size of the document, and the kind of operations (CRUD) you perform on the data. Also, the application code which has to deal with the way you structure the data. Performance depends upon not just the amount of data - indexes, type of operations, RAM memory, hard drives, network, etc.

Comment: thats a read only database that only perform writes during night time (ETL), we perform alot of complex queries(aggregations) on them.

Comment: If you put data from different companies into one collection you may have a security issue, i.e. it can be difficult to separate them properly and in a secure way.

Comment: How many companies?

Comment: mongodb is very flexible to grow document well within 16 MB in size.